# Split using DCG rules

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I need to split dichloropentane using the rules in swi-prolog
this what i try to do

```
stem--> [meth]|[eth]|[prop]|[but]|[pent].

suf --> [ane]|[ene]|[yne].

pre --> [di]|[tri]|[tetre].

hal--> [floro]|[chloro]|[bromo].

?- split_list(['2','3', dichloropentane],['2','3', di,chloro,pent,ane]).
```

In English by using Prolog I need to split `dichloropentane` into `di,chloro,pent,ane` as shown above.

I'm a real newbie for Prolog and please any Prolog pros help me out with the code.

Comment: Do the `'2'` and `'3'` have any particular significance or play a role in how the word splits?

Comment: any numbers not depend on split

Answer (score 2):

try

```
any(S, K) --> {member(S,K)}, S.

stem(S) --> any(S, ["meth","eth","prop","but","pent"]).
suf(S) --> any(S, ["ane","ene","yne"]).
pre(S) --> any(S, ["di","tri","tetre"]).
hal(S) --> any(S, ["floro","chloro","bromo"]).

split_list(S,[A,B,C,D]) :- phrase((pre(A),hal(B),stem(C),suf(D)),S).
```

and you should get

```
?- split_list(`dichloropentane`,P).
P = ["di", "chloro", "pent", "ane"]
```

note the *kind* of quotes: since SWI-Prolog introduced in ver.7 the *type* string, coding for DCG need more care...

*edit*

```
?- atom_codes(dichloropentane,Cs), split_list(Cs,L).
Cs = [100, 105, 99, 104, 108, 111, 114, 111, 112|...],
L = ["di", "chloro", "pent", "ane"]
```

Comment: This code is useful but i want to split atom type word, This code is split as string type.any code is split atom type as atom. And also This is not work if the word is `chloropenane`

Comment: why should it work ? seems mispelled. Just adapt the grammar. For splitting atoms, see my edit... and [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl) documentation for a lot of useful stuff...